# access list in a 2x-nested function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def get_html(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return response.read()


def parse_main(html):
    webpage = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
    table = webpage.find('table', id='itemList')

    for a_tag in table.find_all('a', class_='all'):
        parse_movie(get_html('https://www.somerandommovieswebsite.com' + a_tag['href']))


def parse_movie(html):
    web_page = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
    info = web_page.find('h1', class_="moviename")
    movies.append(info.text)


def main():
    movies = []
    parse_main(get_html('https://www.somerandommovieswebsite.com'))
    print(movies)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How do I access the **movies** list (that is defined in main() function) in **parse_movie** which is nested in **parse_main**. Can't append anything to the list because of "*unresolved referrence 'movies'*" error. Using *nonlocal* didn't help

Answer (score 4):

I think you should *neither* use a global variable here *nor* pass it as an argument:

```
def get_html(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return response.read()


def parse_main(html):
    movies = []
    webpage = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
    table = webpage.find('table', id='itemList')

    for a_tag in table.find_all('a', class_='all'):
        movies.append(
            parse_movie(get_html('https://www.somerandommovieswebsite.com' + a_tag['href']))
        )
    return movies


def parse_movie(html):
    web_page = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
    info = web_page.find('h1', class_="moviename")
    return info.text


def main():
    movies = parse_main(get_html('https://www.somerandommovieswebsite.com'))
    print(movies)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to do it.

**First define globally movies.**

**Second you can just pass a list as a parameter like that.**

Since lists are **passed by reference** and we are appending the list which is define in main function and  we  don't need to return to the main function.

```
def parse_main(html,movies):
    webpage = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
    table = webpage.find('table', id='itemList')

    for a_tag in table.find_all('a', class_='all'):
        parse_movie(get_html('https://www.somerandommovieswebsite.com' + a_tag['href']),movies)


def parse_movie(html,movies):
    web_page = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
    info = web_page.find('h1', class_="moviename")
    movies.append(info.text)


def main():
    movies = []
    parse_main(get_html('https://www.somerandommovieswebsite.com'),movies)
    print(movies)
```

**Third approach is to make a list inside a function and *return* it**

```
def parse_main(html):
    webpage = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
    table = webpage.find('table', id='itemList')
    movies = []
    
    for a_tag in table.find_all('a', class_='all'):
        movies.append (parse_movie(get_html('https://www.somerandommovieswebsite.com' + a_tag['href'])))
    return movies
    
def parse_movie(html):
    web_page = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
    info = web_page.find('h1', class_="moviename")
    return info.text

def main():
    movies = parse_main(get_html('https://www.somerandommovieswebsite.com'))
    print(movies)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `movies` list as an argument and avoid using global variables, in most cases it's better.

The issue was that `movies` was a local variable inside ̀`parse_movie`, meaning it's a different variable than the one defined in your `main`.

I simply passed the ̀`movies` variable from the `main` function down to the `parse_movie` one and added `return` statements.

```
def get_html(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return response.read()


def parse_main(html):
    movies = []
    webpage = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
    table = webpage.find('table', id='itemList')

    for a_tag in table.find_all('a', class_='all'):
        movies.append(parse_movie(get_html('https://www.somerandommovieswebsite.com' + a_tag['href'])))
    return movies


def parse_movie(html):
    web_page = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
    info = web_page.find('h1', class_="moviename")
    return info.text


def main():
    movies = parse_main(get_html('https://www.somerandommovieswebsite.com'))
    print(movies)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach would be using a global variable. But you should avoid using global variables whenever possible. You can change your code something like this and avoid using global variables and passing the variable as parameter.

```
def get_html(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return response.read()


def parse_main(html):
    parse_movies = []
    webpage = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
    table = webpage.find('table', id='itemList')

    for a_tag in table.find_all('a', class_='all'):
        parse_movies.append(parse_movie(get_html('https://www.somerandommovieswebsite.com' + a_tag['href'])))
    return movies


def parse_movie(html):
    web_page = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
    info = web_page.find('h1', class_="moviename")
    return info.text


def main():
    movies = parse_main(get_html('https://www.somerandommovieswebsite.com'))
    print(movies)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

movies is a local variable inside your main function, so it's normal your function doesn't find it, either make it global (not always a good idea) or pass it as an argument.